# In Linux : How can I create a symbolic link to a file whose name starts with a dash/minus sign ?

Tags: linux, symlink

How can I create a symbolic link to a file whose name **starts** with a dash/minus sign (-) : ?

I have this (**-1** is a file name) :

*-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Mar  9 04:35 **-1***

I want this :

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Mar  9 04:35 **-1**

lrwx... 1 root root 2 Mar  8 14:56 **myLink -> -1**

============================================

Note that I **don't want** this

lrwx... 1 root root 2 Mar  8 14:56 myLink -> **./-1**

I want :

lrwx... 1 root root 2 Mar  8 14:56 myLink -> **-1**

I tried

ln -s ".-1" myLink

ln -s "./-1" myLink

ln -s "-1" myLink

None of them works…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `--` to signal that you're done passing options :

```
ln -s -- -1 myLink
```

This way `ln` will not try to interpret `-1` as an option.
Note this will work with many programs, not just `ln`.

Answer (score 2):

Put `--` after the `-s` to tell getopt that you're done giving it options:

```
ln -s -- -1 foo
```

Comment: Note that you can use the same technique (`--` after options) for `rm` too, when you don't want your file anymore.  (And more generally: for any application using `getopt(3)`).